# Extracting certain words from a text file using tr and awk

Tags: bash, awk

this has been giving me a lot of trouble

```
URL: http://123.123.123.123
file: php
124.124.124.124|user1|email|phone

URL: http://1.2.3.4
file: php
2.1.3.1|userx|emailx|phonex
```

and the file contains more sets of data just like this one

i used

```
grep http -A 3|tr '\n' ' '|tr '|' ' '|awk '{print $2,$7,$8}'|tr ' ' ':'
```

the outcome is only from the first set of data

```
123.123.123.123:email:phone
```

intended outcome

```
123.123.123.123:email:phone
1.2.3.4:emailx:phonex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Awk anyway, you can get rid of `grep` and `tr`.

If you can rely on the empty line to separate arguments, try `RS='\n\n'`. Here's a refactoring which instead extracts the information from the third line after the hit.

```
awk '/http/ { l=2; ip=$0; sub(/.*\/\//, "", ip); next }
l && --l == 0 { tail=$0; sub(/^[^|]*[|][^|]*[|]/, "", tail);
    sub(/[|]/, ":", tail); print ip ":" tail }'
```

Perhaps `/^URL:/` would be a better regex than `/http/` for finding the beginning of a record.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like that:

```
awk -F\| '
    /^URL:/ { sub(/.*\/\//,""); url=$0; next   }
      NF==4 { printf "%s:%s:%s\n", url, $3, $4 }
' file
```

Comment: The first argument to sub doesn't have to be an ERE token. `sub(".*//", "")` works equally fine and is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk 'gsub("[|]", ":", $!(NF = NF))' RS= OFS= FS='.+//|\n[^|]*[|][^|]*'
```

> 

```
123.123.123.123:email:phone
1.2.3.4:emailx:phonex
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

The `script.ed`

```
g/^$/d
g|^URL: http://|s|||\
+d
%s/^.*user[^|]*//
g/./;+j
%s/|/:/g
,p
Q
```

---

Run

```
ed -s file.txt < script.ed
```

Answer (score 0):

I would exploit [`getline` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Plain-Getline.html) for this task as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
URL: http://123.123.123.123
file: php
124.124.124.124|user1|email|phone

URL: http://1.2.3.4
file: php
2.1.3.1|userx|emailx|phonex
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS=":"}sub(/^URL: /,""){url=$0;getline;getline;print url,$3,$4}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
http://123.123.123.123:email:phone
http://1.2.3.4:emailx:phonex
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) is pipe (`|`) whilst output field separator (`OFS`) is colon (`:`), I use two effects of `sub`: alteration of line and return value, if alteration occurred I save current line (with leading `URL:`  removed by `sub`) I do use getline twice to get line after next line, after that I `print` `url`, 3rd and 4th columns.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -00 -nE 'say join":",$1,$2,$3 if /\/\/(.*)\n.*\n.*\|(\w+)\|(\w+)/' file

123.123.123.123:email:phone
1.2.3.4:emailx:phonex
```